# Displaying (Last Name, First Name) in the DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

DataGridView is connected to the DB using bindingSource.

```
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
    GetData("SELECT [last_name] + ', ' + [first_name] AS [NAME], patient_id AS [CHART#], birth_date AS [DOB] FROM patient");


    private void GetData(string selectCommand)
    {
        try
        {
            // Specify a connection string. Replace the given value with a 
            // valid connection string for a Northwind SQL Server sample
            // database accessible to your system.

            // Create a new data adapter based on the specified query.
            dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, DQLCommon.ConnectionString);

            // Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and
            // delete commands based on selectCommand. These are used to
            // update the database.
            OleDbCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

            // Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            dataAdapter.Fill(table);
            bindingSource1.DataSource = table;
            DataGridViewColumn column1 = dataGridView1.Columns[0];
            column1.Width = Convert.ToInt16(Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Width) * 0.5);
            DataGridViewColumn column2 = dataGridView1.Columns[1];
            column2.Width = Convert.ToInt16(Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Width) * 0.23);
            DataGridViewColumn column3 = dataGridView1.Columns[2];
            column3.Width = Convert.ToInt16(Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Width) * 0.27);
        }
        catch (OleDbException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed in loading patient list.");
        }
    }
```

I expected the name is displayed as <Last Name>, <First Name>, but separated by period(.) not comma(,) like following picture.

[image]

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
    GetData("SELECT [last_name] + ', ' + [first_name] AS [NAME], patient_id AS [CHART#], birth_date AS [DOB] FROM patient");
```

there's a comma in the GetData command. try using a . :

```
    GetData("SELECT [last_name] + '. ' + [first_name] AS [NAME], patient_id AS [CHART#], birth_date AS [DOB] FROM patient");
```

Comment: @CathalMF but he wants the names to be separated by a period, then why get the data with a comma?

Comment: I don't know why try using a period(.) instead of comma(,). Anyway I tried it but still the result is the same as before.

Comment: @Don You requested the names to be separated by a period instead of a comma. The only place in your code where you get the [Name] is in the GetData command. 
In the GetData command you wrote the following:
_("Select [last_name] + ', ' + [first_name] AS [NAME]_ etc.etc.
After **[last_name]** and before **[first_name]** you used a comma to separate the values. 
If your question was the values to be separated by a period (.) instead of a comma, then you should use a period to separate the names.